# Python os.system ping siempre da la misma respuesta

Tags: python

Buenas este es mi programa, el problema es que quiero hacer ping a varias direcciones y si hay algo en la red por ejemplo el router me dice que hay algo en esa dirección (192.168.1.1) Pero si pongo otra direccion, por ejemplo la (192.168.1.2) En la que no hay nada y no me da respuesta el ping tambien me dice que hay algo

```
import os
ip= ("192.168.1.2")

respuesta = os.system("ping -n 2 " + ip )


if respuesta == 0:

  print (ip, '  Hay algo!')

else:

print (ip, '  No hay nada!')
```

Comment: Ejecutado en windows 10 con python 3.7.4, tu código funciona sin problemas. Resultado: http://prntscr.com/p0al75

Comment: Yo lo estoy ejecutando desde windows 7, crees que ese puede ser el problema? y en caso de cambiar a win10 las personas que ejecuten ese codigo les funcionaria bien? un saludo y gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He probado tu código y me pasa lo mismo que a ti (en Windows 10), ya que devuelve:
`Paquetes: enviados = 2, recibidos = 2, perdidos = 0` para todos los casos, por lo que la respuesta siempre es 0.

Por otro lado en la documentación de os.system, recomiendan utilizar el modulo subprocess
[os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

Después de mucho probar he encontrado esta solución:

```
import subprocess

ip= (192.168.1.1) # Si
#ip= (192.168.1.2) # No

def ping(ip):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '2', '-w', '2', ip])
    p.wait()
    return 'Si' if p.poll()==0 else 'No'

print(ping(ip))
```

En la que devolverá 'Si' si hay algo y 'No' si no hay nada

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, parece que esto funciona!! Podrías decirme donde has encontrado que recomiendan utilizar el módulo subprocess si no es mucha molestia? un saludo y muchas gracias :))

Comment: Hola @Stefan, en el enlace que puse en la respuesta (os.system) viene indicado en el último párrafo.

Comment: Uy! Que despistado jajaja lo siento! :)